# Rest API - search for term across all columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, rest

I have a list with the following fields: `ID`, `Title`, `Location`, `Manager`

I currently have search set up such that if I enter in a term, it returns all the items with that term in the `Title`:

```
../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=ID&$filter=substringof(%27MY_SEARCH_TERM%27,Title)
```

This works, but how would I update my query string so that it returns the items with my search term across all fields and not just on `Title`?

I've considered doing `substringof(%27MY_SEARCH_TERM%27,Title)` OR `substringof(%27MY_SEARCH_TERM%27,Facility)`, etc. but this isn't manageable when there's a lot of fields in the list.

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of REST Search EndPoint and target the list path to search upon

Format is

```
http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='MY_SEARCH_TERM+path:"http://server/lists/MyList"'
```

Comment: The Search API produces a different XML format than the List one though. I'm only concerned/allowed to change the query. I'm expected to have the same XML structure.